# Macbook Pro's screen turns off randomly

Tags: macbook-pro

I have a Macbook Pro (bought in Dec2014). It seems to be working fine everywhere but recently, the screen turns off randomly and this is happening quite often. So can someone suggest something or what's the problem?

Comment: probably not applicable, but just in case, have you checked your serial# against the video issues some models were having? (https://www.apple.com/support/macbookpro-videoissues/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're not getting a magnet next to the lid-closed magnet (hall effect) sensor. Setting one MacBook [Pro] on top of another is enough to do this. So is wearing one of those woo-woo magnetic health bracelets while you use it.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I have a surface and its pen is magnetic. I was keeping the pen close to that area of Mac and that's why it was happening.